# How to use Intent Chaining without slots in Alexa?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create an Alexa skill. I only have one intent (LightOnIntent) that it will play audio. I wanted the user to just start the skill and immediately be redirected to the intent for the audio (without the user saying anything else). The Intent Chaining doesn't work if the intent has no slots to fill. How could I solve? Here is the code:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = 
    `<speak>
        <amazon:effect name="whispered">Welcome.</amazon:effect>.
    </speak>`;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        .addDelegateDirective({
            name: 'LightOnIntent',
            slots: {}
        })
        .getResponse();
}
```

};

```
const LightOnIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LightOnIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    const {requestEnvelope, responseBuilder} = handlerInput;
    
    const audioUrl = Util.getS3PreSignedUrl("Media/ding.mp3").replace(/&/g,'&amp;');

    const speakOutput = `<audio src="${audioUrl}"/>`;
    
    return responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
        //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
        .getResponse();
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Couple of follow up questions:

1. What is the purpose of the intent for the audio? Since you mentioned that you don't want any slots for the intent, do you plan to have any logic for intent confirmation?
2. What happens after the audio plays? Do you expect the user to reply?

Suppose you want to just play audio after user invokes the skill, why not play the audio clip as part of the response to the LaunchRequest?  Something like this:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
const audioUrl = Util.getS3PreSignedUrl("Media/ding.mp3").replace(/&/g,'&amp;');
    const speakOutput = 
    `<speak>
        <amazon:effect name="whispered">Welcome.</amazon: effect>.
        <audio src="${audioUrl}"/>
    </speak>`;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speakOutput)
         .shouldEndSession(true)
        .getResponse();
}
```

Additionally if you want to provide a richer audio experience, you can use [APL for Audio](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-presentation-language/apl-for-audio-reference.html) instead of `speak`